# Codename One: Implementing a tracking feature and performing calculations

Tags: codenameone

I would like to implement a calculation to track fluid intake.  This should get input from a user, perform a calculation and display the result.

As suggested in a previous post, I have updated my code (from the method AddItem()) as follows.

```
addItem.addComponent(selectItem);
    TextField quantity = new TextField("", "Quantity (ml or g)", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
    addItem.addComponent(quantity);
    Button add = new Button("Add");
    addItem.addComponent(add);       
    TextArea results = new TextArea("Results");
    addItem.addComponent(results);
    //TextArea total = new TextArea("Add Item");
    //addItem.addComponent(total);

//--------------------------------------------------------------
    add.addActionListener((ActionEvent ev) -> {
        Storage s = Storage.getInstance();
int total = 0;
String num = quantity.getText();
Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
total = total + num2;
// Save the "Hello World" string to storage
s.writeObject("volume", total);
Container ctrResult = new Container(new GridLayout(1,3)); 
//Define a new container associated to a gridlayout with 1 row and 1 column
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label("Volume"));
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label(Integer.toString(total)));
ctrResult.addComponent(new Label(Integer.toString(total/volume*100)));
//Because you use a value inside a function, addItem should be initialized as final
addItem.addComponent(ctrResult);
    });
//--------------------------------------------------------------

    return addItem;
```

This code displays the user input (number from user). I would like to save the total and use this in the calculation to update what is being saved. Also, if the user adds another quantity, a new row is displayed, but I would like the existing row to be updated.

Additionally, I would like to perform another calculation to calculate percentage, using the following variable (in another method called Settings()).

```
TextField volume = new TextField("", "Volume (ml)", 4, TextArea.NUMERIC);
    settings.addComponent(volume);
```

The calculation would be: total/volume*100.

Both methods are public.

I would therefore appreciate any help and guidance on how this could be implemented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update an existing value in a component that's already displayed on the screen you need a reference to that component. So you need to store the pointer to that component somewhere.

Once you have a component reference for a `Label` you can just invoke `setText()` on it to set its value to anything you want based on your logic.

You can store the component references within your class file or by using [putClientProperty](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) on your parent `Form`. Notice that the latter approach is slightly more challenging.